# Is there way to pass parameter from Jenkins job to RobotFramework and/or python script? Can I do it with and without Jenkinsfile?

Tags: python, jenkins, robotframework

I want to run python or robot script in Jenkins with chosen parameter. I know how to make parameterized job, but I don't know how to pass chosen parameter to python or robot script. In example, I want to decide role (Aa, Bb, Cc or Dd) from Jenkins and run my test (robot or python file) with decided role. I can do this locally for robot file trough cmd prompt (which can be done trough Jenkins too since Jenkins uses cmd also) with:

`robot -d results -v role:{role i want to use} -t testiwanttorun filewhichincludesthattest`

So I want to replace that {role i want to use} with chosen parameter from Jenkins so I don't have to change configuration each time I want to change the role. Another example would be test which I want to run on different browsers depending on day, so I want to decide which browser I want use on this build.

I'm also eager to do this easier way without using commands like above. Hope I explained problem well enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is just the same as when you pass a variable in a local command line interface.

Your choice parameter has a name, so use the name to pass it as an option in your command:

```
>robot -d results -v role:%ROLE% -t testiwanttorun filewhichincludesthattest
```

or bash:

```
$ robot -d results -v role:$ROLE -t testiwanttorun filewhichincludesthattest
```

Similarly with the browser choices.

This has also been shown on many other places, e.g. here: https://geekdudes.wordpress.com/2019/08/02/jenkins-run-shell-script-add-parameters-to-job/

Comment: Thank you. %ROLE% works well for me. How about running python file from cmd and passing same parameter for that script? I can run that file simply:

 `python testfile.py`

How I can pass that parameter for that file too?

Comment: The Jenkins-command part will be the same, but you need to process the options in Python somehow. Try to Google first.